# How to empty ObservableCollection at specific times in C#

Tags: c#, mvvm, observablecollection

I am struggling with MVVM and WPF in C#. I would like to create a datagrid that displays an ObservableCollection which stores the name and the time of when an event occurred. This datagrid and ObservableCollection  should be made empty at specific times (at 10:30am, 2pm, 6pm and 2am) and start collecting a fresh new list of events.

I am trying not to use a timer job (I read that they are resource consuming). **Would it be possible to check the time every time a new event occurs, and depending on what time it is, either empty the ObservableCollection or just add the event to the current O.C list?**

For example:
If the time is exactly 10:30am or 2pm or 6pm or 2am: first empty the ObservableCollection, then enter the new event in the ObservableCollection.

If the time is after 10:30am or 2pm or 6pm or 2am but the ObservableCollection  has not been emptied (because no event occurred exactly at those times)  i.e. This is first event to occur after the "emptying times": first - empty the ObservableCollection, then enter the new event in the ObservableCollection.

Else just enter the new event in the ObservableCollection (because the ObservableCollection has already been emptied since it is not the first event to occur after the "emptying times")

Comment: "I am trying not to use a timer job (I read that they are resource consuming)" - if you're talking about `System.Threading.Timer`, then you've been misinformed. The timer is handled by the OS, and you app is notified through an IO Completion Port, and your delegate will be invoked on a ThreadPool thread. No thread is blocked in-between ticks.

Comment: Timers are only costly when their usage is abused. You need something to fire at a specific point in the future, so you really need a timer.

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting me. If I were to use a timer job would it have to check every single minute if the time is equal to 10:30am , 2pm , 6pm or 2am? and if it is, it should empty the ObservableCollection? Please may you guide me on the most efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be the most efficient approach, but it might be a plausible approach. I also don't really know what your application is (if it's a Web app) but if it's a WPF/MVVM application, when you need your timer to start, calculate when the next interval is (so if you start the application and system clock, if it's acceptable to use, says it's 9:21 AM, next interval will be 10:30 AM).

Then, start a timer that will time out at the next interval, and then implement the timer callback delegate to do whatever you need to do at that interval.

If you're using .NET 4.5 look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)